# Struggling to understand why a VM is so expensive

Tags: azure

I've been moving a few web sites around Azure of late, chasing a cost model that could be sustainable (web roles to apps to VMs of various configuration). I thought I'd found the perfect match: SSD, 2vCPUs and 4GB. Just enough to squeeze stuff in and with swallowable costs.

However, after a month's worth of billing, it seem this VM doesn't cost the estimated £35.93, but TWICE that.

[image: My chosen VM: 2 vCPUs, 4GB, SSD]

I accept that this was estimated, but when costs are coming in TWICE that, I can't sustain it.

So, is there something I'm missing?

I notice that within the Resource Group is a Storage Account.

[image: Resource Group cost breakdown]

I *think* that this is holding the hard disks on which the VM is based. But if I'm quoted an 8GB local SSD, is this not in the cost or is the OS disk coming out of this Storage Account as extra?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the disk cost.
The price of the VM includes the 8GB SSD, but this is your local paging drive, the D: drive. This is a disk that is passed through from the local host, not backed by any resilient storage, and so is only for transient data use.

The C: drive on your VM however is not included in the price quoted for the VM (i'm not saying I agree with this approach, but that is what it is). For the C: drive you are using premium storage, which is fairly expensive, this is because you chose the S variant, which is designed to support premium storage. If you choose the non-S series you can use standard storage, however I don't believe the B series has a non-S variant, unlike all the other sizes.

Comment: Yeah, somewhat disingenuous, really. That makes total sense. Thanks for the clarification. I was on spinny disks but the performance was pants. Looks like I'll be heading to 1&1. Shame.

Comment: Yeah I’m not a fan of this approach. I understand the reasoning as it splits the cost of what you get charged when the VM is on vs off, but it leads to confusion and feelings of being ripped off.